# Vertically centered text keeps going under icon

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a alert for my project which looks good but when I make it a mobile page the text goes under the icon. I want it to stay aligned beside the icon.

HTML:

```
<div class="rds-alert">
    <img class="rds-alert-icon"/>
    <div class="rds-alert-message">
        <span class="rds-alert-so">Congratulation</span> Your submission has been approved.
    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rds-alert-so{
    font-size:30px;
}
.rds-alert-icon{
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-right:12px;
}
.rds-alert-message{
    display:inline;
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0f2rpvc8/

Comment: I don't see any icons in your fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```css
.rds-alert-so {
    font-size:30px;
}
.rds-alert-icon {
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    margin-right:12px;
    display:table-cell;
}
.rds-alert-message {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.rds-alert {
    display:table-row;
}
```

```html
<div class="rds-alert">
    <img class="rds-alert-icon" />
    <div class="rds-alert-message"> <span class="rds-alert-so">Congratulation</span> Your submission has been approved.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you change table-row to table it should.

Answer (score 1):

or

```
.rds-alert-icon {
float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Lfkrxup/